# How to write the expression for the following vectors? (ratio problem)

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields, scalar-fields

The diagram shows a parallelogram $ABCD$. $E$ is such a point on $CD$ such that $BD:EB=1:3$. Write expressions for these vectors.
(a) DC
 (b) CD
 (c) AC
 (d) AE
 (e) DE

I solved the first three: $DC = b, \,CD = -b, \,AC = b + a$. I am confused with the next one that requires finding $BE$. I know that $BD$ is $1/4$ of something and $EB$ is $3/4$ of something, but I'm not sure what is that something. Please, help me understand this part. The answer for $AE$ is supposed to be $b+$3/4$a$
I can do the rest of it once I understand it. Thanks!

Edit: added a new picture link of the question

[Parallelogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCZvE.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a typo? BD and EB are clearly not parallel. What does a ratio of 1:3 even mean in that case?

Comment: @BenjaminWang Hi, I added a new picture, maybe you can understand this one, straight outta book. And yeah they aren't parallel.

Comment: Edited my answer. You should inform the publisher of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Your question and answer don't match. If AE = $b +3a/4$, then the condition on E should be that CE:EB=1:3.

A **red flag** to me is that the question is using ":" notation when the points involved are not collinear.

[image]

As you can see, the picture might have confused you, because in general, the point E might lie outside the line segment CD.

Note the absolute value on $\lambda$, so there's always a positive and a negative solution, corresponding to two points either side of D.

Comment: Thanks so much!